# Hide WooCommerce product from specific category archive after a time period

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, action-scheduler

I have created a "New arrival" product category section in my WooCommerce website. I want product assigned to a new category will hide or will be auto removed from the "new arrival" category and remain visible in other categories if one or more categories are assigned to it.

**Details & explanations:**

1. There is "new arrival" section in home page.
2. In this product listing from the new arrival category.
3. I want to hide or remove the product from the "new arrival" section after 15 days from the published date.
4. But after 15 days it will remain visible in the other categories if one or more categories are assign to this product.

**Example:** A product "Red T shirt" is assigned "new arrival" and "sale" categories, then after 15 days, this product will be hidden or removed from the "new arrival section", but will remain visible in the "sale" category.

Here is my code so far:

```
// Add a custom action to schedule a job when a product is published
add_action('woocommerce_new_product', 'schedule_product_visibility_change', 10, 2);
function schedule_product_visibility_change($product_id, $product)
{
    // Schedule the job to run after 15 days
    wp_schedule_single_event(time() + 15 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, 'auto_hide_product_from_new_arrival', array($product_id));
}

// Hook to run when the scheduled job is triggered
add_action('auto_hide_product_from_new_arrival', 'auto_hide_product_from_new_arrival_callback');
function auto_hide_product_from_new_arrival_callback($product_id)
{
    // Get product categories
    $categories = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'product_cat', array('fields’ => ‘ids'));
    // Check if the product is in the "New Arrival" category
    if (in_array('new-arrival-category-id', $categories)) {
        // Update product visibility
        wp_set_object_terms($product_id, 'exclude-from-catalog', 'visibility', true);
    }
}

// Restore product visibility if it’s removed from the “New Arrival” category before 15 days
add_action('woocommerce_remove_product_cat', 'restore_product_visibility_on_category_removal', 10, 2);
function restore_product_visibility_on_category_removal($product_id, $category)
{
    // Get product categories
    $categories = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids'));
    // Check if the product was in the "New Arrival" category
    if ($category->term_id === 'new-arrival-category-id' && !in_array('new-arrival-category-id', $categories)) {
        // Restore product visibility
        wp_remove_object_terms($product_id, 'exclude-from-catalog', 'visibility');
    }
}
```

But my code is incomplete and doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Update** *(using Action Scheduler)*

You are complicating things for nothing, and there are multiple mistakes in your code… You just need to schedule "new-arrival" category unassignment after 15 days, so the product will not be visible anymore in "new-arrival" category, but will stay visible in other categories assigned to it.

Now here, I use **[Action Scheduler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/action-scheduler/)** plugin, that is a reliable, scalable and traceable job queue for background processing, as WordPress scheduler is not really reliable. 
Note that [Action Scheduler library](https://github.com/woocommerce/action-scheduler) is included / used by *WooCommerce* and *WooCommerce Subscriptions*, but you still need to install the plugin, to use the Action Scheduler functions.
The documentations is on [ActionScheduler.org](https://actionscheduler.org/).

First, you will install/enable Action Scheduler plugin.

Then use the following:

```php
// Add a custom action to schedule a job when a product is published
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'schedule_product_category_unassign', 10, 1 );
function schedule_product_category_unassign( $product ) {
    // Make sure that is a new product
    if ( $product->get_meta('_unassign_task') ) 
        return;

    $schedule_time = strtotime('+15 days'); // Schedule the job to run in 15 days
    $schedule_time = strtotime('+5 minutes'); // For testing on 5 minutes (to be removed or commented)
    $schedule_hook = 'unassign_new_arrival_product_category'; // Custom schedule hook

    if ( as_schedule_single_action( $schedule_time, $schedule_hook, array( $product->get_id() ) ) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data('unassign_cat', 'pending'); // Tag the product
    } else {
        $product->update_meta_data('unassign_cat', 'failed'); // Tag the product
    }
}

// Hook to run when the scheduled job is triggered
add_action( 'unassign_new_arrival_product_category', 'unassign_new_arrival_product_category_callback', 10, 1 );
function unassign_new_arrival_product_category_callback( $product_id )
{
    $product  = wc_get_product($product_id); // Get the product object
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat'; // Product category taxonomy
    $term_ids = $product->get_category_ids('edit'); // Get product categories

    if( empty($term_ids) ) return; // Be sure that there are product categories

    // Loop through assigned product categories
    foreach( $term_ids as $key => $term_id ) {
        // Check if the product is in the "New Arrival" category
        if ( term_exists('new-arrival', $taxonomy) && 'new-arrival' === get_term_by('term_id', $term_id, $taxonomy)->slug ) {
            unset($term_ids[$key]); // Remove 'new-arrival' category ID from the array

            $product->set_category_ids($term_ids); // Update product categories
            $product->update_meta_data('unassign_cat', 'complete'); // Update tagged product
            return $product->save(); // Save product changes
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

In the code, I use `unassign_cat` custom field to tag the product ensuring that is a newly added product and allowing to follow the schedule task status.

**For testing, I use a schedule time of 5 minutes**, so after testing, comment or remove from the first function the following line (to get a schedule time of 15 days):

```php
$schedule_time = strtotime('+5 minutes'); // For testing on 5 minutes (to be removed or commented)
```

You will be able to follow schedule tasks on admin "Tools" > "Scheduled Actions" dashboard

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.


 its still not working 


 also I have tried this code Please check and suggest what to do.


 I have also tried to   fetch product by the  prodcut publish date and product modified date and assign  to the "recent" prodcut category but the desired out put not recived .


 I just want to the keep the product less then 15 days from the publish date from current date and exclude all  other product which publish date is greater then 15 days from the current  date .